# AmCharts 5 Zooming into Location?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

Somewhat new to using AmCharts 5, and I'm just trying to trigger a simple zoom into a location on a map. However, no matter what tutorial I follow, I cannot replicate the results that others do.

I've got a Codepen setup so that you can play around with the code.
https://codepen.io/tonycre8-the-bold/pen/wvQZojM

I've tried using the following function to get it to work:

```js
// Get London & Stamford geolocations
var locations = [
    { id: "london", title: "London", geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [51.5074, 0.1278] } },
    { id: "stamford", title: "Stamford", geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [52.6466, -0.4833]} }
];

// Zoom into London
locationChart.events.on("ready", function() {
    locationChart.zoomToGeoPoint({ latitude: 51.5074, longitude: 0.1278 }, 4, true);
});
```

I'm really not sure how to go with this as the version 5 documentation links to version 4 code that doesn't work with the v5 implementation. It's all a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue:

Make sure to use your PolygonSeries for event handling instead of the Chart.

```js
// Zoom into London
locationPolygonSeries.events.on("datavalidated", function() {
    // changed from locationChart.events.on(...
    locationChart.zoomToGeoPoint({
        longitude: -0.1262,
        latitude: 51.5002
    }, 3);
});
```